Velocity change after a 15-deg climb in one second
I am trying to make a very simple model to simulate aircraft motion, using velocity only. I don't want to make it complex by using lift, drag, thrust, etc.
When an airplane, flying at 200 m/s at time 0, pitches up 15 deg at time 1 without increasing thrust, is it reasonable to say that its velocity will decrease to 193.2 m/s at time 2 and it climbs to 50 m?
I calculated those numbers using vector sum shown below.
200 * cos(15) = 193.2 (the length of the blue arrow below)


No. Closer to 197 $\frac{m}{s}$.

Can you please show me how you calculated 197 m/s?

By assuming conservation of energy one can equate $m g \Delta h = 1/2 m (v_1^2-v_2^2)$. With this you see that the answer should be 197 $\frac{m}{s}$. While I think it is an interesting idea to simplify flight dynamics calculation, I do not think that triangles are physically correct... However perhaps it is enough for your needs? Though it might be arbitrarily incorrect...

@U_flow Energy conservation is not the right thing to use here. The thrust is unchanged, not turned off. Even if it were turned off, energy conservation would still be wrong since it doesn't account for drag.

Basically by using energy conservation, you're simulating a projectile. That's not an aircraft by any stretch of the imagination!

If an airplane flying at 200m/s suddenly pitches up of 15° it either stalls or get destroyed... You cannot use only velocity to describe the flight physics of an aircraft... unless your aircraft is a spherical cow in vacuum

@Chris Energy conservation is the right tool to use here because the thrust is not turned off! As the aircraft is in level flight before the pitch up, we know that Thrust = Drag. After the pitch up maneuver, momentarily we can assume that still T=D however with the addition of the gravity component. I agree that after some time the aircraft will settle to its new equilibrium, but not in one second. For this reason, energy conservation can be used as an approximation as all other forces stay roughly the same on this time-scale.

In the real world, if one were to instantaneously command a flight path angle (gamma) of 15 deg from level flight, there would be a significant angle-of-attack transient. Therefore, for the sake of this thought-experiment question, if you assume angle-of-attack is very small throughout and somehow gamma makes an unphysical step change from 0 to 15 deg, then thrust and drag haven’t changed in that instant so still cancel each other out. Then, the deceleration rate is equal to simply g*sin(gamma) or approximately 2.54 m/s/s.
Of course, as the velocity decreases over time, drag will be less and thrust will change slightly with velocity and altitude. However, over only one second, the assumption of thrust remaining equal and opposite to drag is reasonable. 200 - 2.54 = 197.46

No. The speed will change to whatever balances thrust, lift, drag, and weight. There's no way around it.
The simplest model you can make that has any degree of accuracy is to treat weight as a constant, lift and drag as functions only of velocity, and thrust as a variable. This approximates the hands-off flight of an airplane at a specific trim setting (so that it always flies the same angle of attack).
Such a plane can't do the maneuver you ask about in your question though- it is unable to pitch up at constant thrust. That requires pitch control, and with it you have to model how lift (and drag, if you like) vary with angle of attack.
